# Passing an object by it's name through HTML to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

It's a pretty simple question and I'm going insane over here googling this all around and getting all these insanely non related answers.
here is the code:

```js
function Banana(boja, duzina) {
  this.boja = boja;
  this.duzina = duzina;
}
var zut = new Banana("zuta", 12);

function fja(obj) {
  var rez = "";
  for (var key in obj)
    var rez += key + " = "
  obj.key + "<br/>";
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = rez;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fja();">klikni</button>
<div id='div1'>xd</div>
```

Is it possible to pass an instance of an object "zut" to this function through HTML? If yes,how,if not,how am I supposed to do it through JS?
I want div1 html to be turned into:

```
boja = zuta
duzina = 12
```

thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Banana(boja, duzina) {
  this.boja = boja;
  this.duzina = duzina;
}
var zut = new Banana("zuta", 12);

function fja(obj) {
  var rez = "";
  for (var key in obj)
    rez += key + " = "+ obj[key] + "<br/>";
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = rez;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fja(zut);">klikni</button>
<div id='div1'>xd</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can, although why your code doesn't work is because

1) - You're re declaring the variable `rez`and assigning to it using `+=`  which is no valid.

2) - `obj.key` is not valid, because there no such property called `key`, To access it you need to use brackets `obj[key]` now`key` will be considered as a variable and it's value will be used to get the property's value.

3) - You missed a `+` in this line `var rez += key + " = " (HERE) obj.key + "<br/>";`

4) - Your call to the method in the html is missing the argument.

you can either use `onclick="fja(new Banana('zuta', 12));`

Or declare the object inline in the HTML, or declare it in the js and pass it name

```
//in the Js
var zut = new Banana("zuta", 12);
//in the HTML
onclick="fja(zut);
```

---

## Example one

```js
function Banana(boja, duzina) {
  this.boja = boja;
  this.duzina = duzina;
}


function fja(obj) {
  var rez = "";
  for (var key in obj)
    rez += key + " = " + obj[key] + "<br/>";
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = rez;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fja(new Banana('zuta', 12));">klikni</button>
<div id='div1'>xd</div>
```

---

## Example Two

```js
function Banana(boja, duzina) {
  this.boja = boja;
  this.duzina = duzina;
}
var zut = new Banana("zuta", 12);

function fja(obj) {
  var rez = "";
  for (var key in obj)
    rez += key + " = " + obj[key] + "<br/>";
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = rez;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fja(zut);">klikni</button>
<div id='div1'>xd</div>
```